# Using groupBy recursively on a backbone.js collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am building an online shop where customers can select different items and customise each in terms of different colours.  At the checkout I would like to group them first of all by item description and then split the returned groups down into further groups of colours.

I can't seem to be able to do this recursively.  This is what I have so far to return the groups of items

```
var groupedItems = this.collection.groupBy(function(model){ return model.get('description');});
```

How could I run it again to take this output and group by colours?  I think I might need to turn the output into a collection again?

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Backbone's groupBy function is just a proxy to underscore's [groupby](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) so you use that. Something like `var groupedColours = _.groupBy(groupedItems, function (item) {return item.get('colour');},this);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jack.  You set me on the right path and now I have something that works!  This is the code I arrived at. 

`var finalGroupedArray = [];
            var groupedItems = this.collection.groupBy(function(model){ return model.get('description');});
            var count = 0;
            for(var description in groupedItems){
                var groupedColours = _.groupBy(groupedItems[Object.keys(groupedItems)[count]], function (item) {return item.get('colour');},this);
                finalGroupedArray.push(groupedColours);
                count++;
            }`

Comment: Glad to help, though I think you forgot to post the code you arrived at.

Comment: heh, yeah, I'm a bit of a Stack noob - I hit return too soon!  I've added it now but it's not formatted it very well

Comment: In general its best to update your question with the relevant information rather (it's also easier to format there), that is if it's part of the question, if it's a solution then you can post it as an answer (though you might have to wait a bit before you can answer your own question).

Comment: ah okay, cheers.  Yeah it won't let me post it yet but I will do after the 8 hour wait! Guess I need to build my rep :). Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to my original question with a solution that Jack set me on the path to, this is the code I used to group a collection by one attribute followed by a subgroup of another attribute.  This uses the underscore groupBy on the result of the Backbone groupBy.

```
var finalGroupedArray = [];
var groupedItems = this.collection.groupBy(function(model){ return model.get('description');});
var count = 0;

for(var description in groupedItems){
    var groupedColours = _.groupBy(groupedItems[Object.keys(groupedItems)[count]], function (item) {return item.get('colour');},this);
    finalGroupedArray.push(groupedColours);
    count++;
}
```